# Can't find where devise create method to create user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Updated**

I want to add more details to this. I have a user model and this user model

```
has_many :trial_subscriptions
attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_subscriptions, :allow_destroy => true
```

I am building a custom form so when a user enters a trial_email, the form will create a new user with an associated trial_subscription

The trial_subscription.rb model inherits from manual_subscription model and manual_subscription inherits from subscription model.

The subscription model

```
belongs_to :user
```

I need to build the associations from the has_many side. Now I am having trouble figuring out where to post the form (getting the @user to be editted) when devise is involve. I need to know where the create method is when the user gets created and hence my question below.

This will be a separate page from normal sign up in a /sales url so I can not add nested fields to the signup form.

---

The rails application that I am working on has devise installed on the user model.

In the routes

I have

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
resources :users
```

the sign up form is in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

I have a users_controller.rb with a new and create method

in the users_controller.rb there is this before_filter

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
```

We have active admin installed. I am still quite new to the code. Since this filter exist I am sure the user is not getting created in this controller.

when I go to

```
/users/sign_up  - there is the sign up page
```

if I do

```
   /users/new - I am redirected to /users/sign_up
```

so I am guessing that the user is getting created in the registrations controller but the new method is 
 this

```
  def new
    session[:qbid] = params[:qbid]
    session[:trial] = params[:trial]
    session[:sublength] = params[:sublength]
    if session[:trial] = true
      @trial_flow = true
    end
    super
  end
```

there is no User.new object getting passed to the view to get edited? I am guessing that devise doesn't need it.

I am getting confused on where the user is getting created because my task is to create a custom form which creates a new user.

I don't know where to post the form to? the registrations_controller?

The user has a has_many subscriptions association and I need to post a form that both create the user and its subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize devise's registrations controller. See [it's doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)
Though the doc shows only how to customize the session controller (login), the steps are similar, you just need name your customized controller differently.

If you are wondering, you can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise) how devises' controllers look.
When you are customizing those, you are going to use inheritance. That is another topic you should read about.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I need to build a custom form and not reusing forms from devise. I want to know where the create method is happening so I can post my form to it whether it is devise or my users controller I am not sure.

Comment: Ok, but do you see how can you completely customize the views there that devise copied into your app's folder? Btw, even if you do not want to use them, you can still check them how they are working, where they need to post, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that I can create the form inside the devise views and have it posted and it should go through the right channel ?

Comment: Let's start from here: "my task is to create a custom form which creates a new user." You write creates a new user. What does that mean? Registering via Devise creates a user, for the user who registers, but creating a user could also mean that you as an admin want to create users for other people. I'm not sure what you need, but you should not mix these two things, especially because devise require the user who is attempting the register, to be logged off when registering. As an admin you need to be logged in already to create more users.

Comment: Another thing: if you simple want to add other fields (including fields of associated models) to the sign up form then you need to customize the views of devise and it's controllers too. You can find how that is done within the the linked pages.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope the extra info answers your question

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check linked page too and let me know if you have more trouble

Comment: I gave you an upvote, I think I had an assumption involve that I can use the same registration controller. Can you take a look at this question? I have moved ahead but still encountering trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585749/customize-route-to-new-user-registration-page-in-devise-simple-form-for-posting