# Customize Route to New User Registration Page in Devise Simple_Form_For Posting new form to Devise Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

an idea - should I be making a new controller that inherits the registrations controller? and then do another

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registration => "newcontroller"}
```

change my trial_signup.html.erb to new.html.erb

and make a new folder in app/views/devise/registrations2/new.html.erb

**Newest Update**
app/views/devise/trial_signup.html.erb

```
<h2>Trial Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => sales_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <%= f.input :first_name, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <%= f.input :last_name, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
  </div>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>    
  <%= f.button :submit,  class: "btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

- this renders my trial_signup.html.erb at sales but when I do submit its looking for user.sales and no user gets created.

---

I have a user.rb model

```
has_many :trial_subscriptions
attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_subscriptions, :allow_destroy => true
```

I have a trial_subscription.rb model that inherits from manual_subscription.rb and that inherits from subscription.rb

Subscription.rb model

```
belongs_to :user
```

---

My task is to create a trial_signup.html.erb to post the form (create the user and its associated trial accounts)

I am trying to learn devise and simple_form_for as I go.

---

in my routes

I have this

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

if I go to users/sign_up I am rendering the app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

I made an identical copy of the new.html.erb to trial_signup.html.erb in

```
app/views/devise/registrations/trial_signup.html.erb
```

I added this to my routes

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "sales", to: "registrations#trial_signup"
  end
```

I may have mistaken the purpose of devise_scope. I don't fully understand this part.

am i getting the sales page using the user model pointing to the registration trial signup action? Please note that I want the trial_signup.html.erb to hit the create method (from devise) in the registration controller. Is it hitting an empty trial_signup action in my registration controller?

I have this in my form

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

- this renders my trial_signup.html.erb at sales but its not posting

---

when I do rake routes I have this

```
new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                                registrations#new
sales GET        /sales(.:format)                                        registrations#trial_signup
```

**I don't have a registration_path? what is it for?

Comment: Why not just modify the new.html.erb? Is there any specific use case for which you are keeping two different sign up pages?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Hi the new.html.erb is for regular sign up and the trial_signup is for signing users for a trial. There are two purposes. I plan to have a custom form with nested attributes to build the association. A user model has many trial_subscriptions.

Comment: See my answer. Let me know if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

With

`<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => sales_path) do |f| %`>

Do `rake routes` and check the path generated for `get "sales"` route(mostly user_sales_path: check under prefix column), pass it as `url` option to the form. Because of this upon form submission your custom `RegistrationsController#trial_signup` action would be called.

Comment: I updated the question, added some details and still running into trouble. I want the form to post to the create method in my custom controller that inherits from devise::registration not hitting the trial_signup action??

Comment: The form is getting rendered but I want

Comment: As per the `rake routes`, you have sales_path so update the path accordingly in the simple_form_for. See my updated answer for the same.

Comment: I have tried it. After I hit the save user button its looking for user.save and says route can't be found. I have also updated my question above.

Comment: I only have new should I have edit, create, and destroy in my routes as well?