# what is resource in simple_form ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am looking at this simple_form_for form (sign up form) (registrations/new.html.erb)

going to users/signup

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

I have looked through the simple_form gem doc on github and checked out the wikis. I have also search for what is a resource on stackoverflow ? I think my question is more like how is simple_form_for using resource? I understand the rest of the code just not this line. I think this form is posting to the registration_path. I do not have a registration_path but I have a

user_registration mapping to the registrations#create method

and my registrations controller inherits from devise registration.

in my routes I have this

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resource` is not simple_form specific but devise specific. It is a method defined in `DeviseController` which gets the actual resource stored in the instance variable of Devise model i.e., `User` model in your case.

Refer to [DeviseController class](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb) code in GitHub to checkout the resource method.

As you are customizing the `Devise::RegistrationsController`, when you submit the form `create` action of your custom RegistrationsController would be called. If you have not overridden the `create` action in your custom controller then the call would propagate to the parent class I.e., `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`

Comment: Will you answer this too? and thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585749/customize-route-to-user-registration-page-in-devise-scope-simple-form-for